# How to open default browser options on preference changed?

Tags: android, kotlin, browser, webview, settings

Hello I am trying to open the default browser options on SwitchPreferenceCompat clicked. So that the user can select the app & set as default.
here is my code:

```
// prefs
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="General Settings">

        <SwitchPreferenceCompat
            app:key="default_browser"
            app:title="Set Default Browser"
            app:defaultValue="false">

        </SwitchPreferenceCompat>

    </PreferenceCategory>

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

And Settings Activity:

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
..
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings, SettingsFragment())
            .commit()

        ...
    }

    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs, rootKey)
            
        }

override fun onPreferenceTreeClick(preference: Preference?): Boolean {
            when (preference!!.key) {
                "default_browser" -> {

                    return true
                }
        }
return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preference)
} 
...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution :

```
when (preference!!.key) {
            "default_browser" -> {
                return try {
                    val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_DEFAULT_APPS_SETTINGS)
                    requireContext().startActivity(intent)
                    true
                } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                    view?.snack("Error")
                   false
                }
            }
         }
```